# Каким названием объединены полки для хранения ключей?

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется этот "шкафчик" для хранения ключей? Щит? Панель?

Answer (score 1):

Ключница — навесной шкаф для хранения ключей. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0